# Issue with printing an array list

Tags: java, for-loop, arraylist, println

I'm currently using a for loop to print elements in a list. It works fine and prints all the lines, however, nothing prints after the for loop itself.

For example:

```
for(int i=0;i<=petlist.size();i++)
{
    System.out.println(petlist.get(i));
}

System.out.println("Test");
```

Test won't print. Is there any other way to do this? Or am I just missing something?

Comment: Hint: an exception is being thrown.

Comment: Also, pay special attention to your loop termination expression.

Comment: Heh, just caught it (unlike this code).

Comment: just print the exception, I think there should have some exceptions!

Comment: ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Comment: So far six of us have noticed the problem. Think long and hard about how array indices work.

Comment: Wow, thank you very much guys. I feel so dumb right now.

Comment: It's all good, we all make silly mistakes :)

Comment: tyr this for(int i = 0; i < petlist.size(); i++)

Comment: it's funny how people are jacking answers.. there is 5 answers of same thing and 2 are posted 2 minutes after that say same thing / less :)..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The loop should continue untill `i < petlist.size()`. In your code it will be an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

```
for(int i=0; i < petlist.size();i++) {}
```

Comment: thanks @user3170143. welcome to the so :). if you think any of the answers was helpful you can accept those by clicking the check mark.

Answer (score 0):

Your loop should like

```
for(int i=0;i<petlist.size();i++)
{
    System.out.println(petlist.get(i));
}

System.out.println("Test");
```

I have removed =< to <

Comment: Thanks a lot, I don't know why I overlooked that.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
for(int i=0;i<petlist.size();i++)
{
    try{
       System.out.println(petlist.get(i));
    }
    catch(Exception ex){
       ex.println();
    }
}
```

I believe this should catch your error if you have it!

But I believe your loop never ends so it never gets out of it, I believe its the <= needs to be <

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `i<=petlist.size()` use `i<petlist.size()` otherwise it will give IndexOutOfBound Exception.

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int i=0;i<petlist.size();i++)
{
    System.out.println(petlist.get(i));
}

System.out.println("Test");
```